# RelayCommand in C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, delegates, icommand

I am learning MVVM for C# Silverlight development from

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

and I am confused about the RelayCommand class mentioned in the context. The code is:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
#region Fields

readonly Action<object> _execute;
readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;        

#endregion // Fields

#region Constructors

public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
: this(execute, null)
{
}

public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
{
    if (execute == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;           
}
#endregion // Constructors

#region ICommand Members

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
}

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _execute(parameter);
}

#endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

For which I dont really understand how `_execute` and `_canExecute` works in this case. (I am new to C# and even not sure what's Action and Predicate. I know they are delegates but whats the difference between them and how they works?) 

 And also, in the program, I didnt get the line

```
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
```

Can someone give me a explaination about this, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RelayCommand` requires two pieces of information:

1. What code should run when the command is executed (the `_execute` action)
2. What code should run to determine if this command can be executed (the `_canExecute` predicate)

An `Action` is a delegate that represents a method that returns `void`.  In this case the `_execute` action takes one parameter (an `object`) and returns `void`.

A `Predicate` is a delegate that takes a value and returns a boolean result.  In this case the `_canExecute` predicate takes an `object` value and returns a `bool`.

Both the `_execute` and `_canExecute` values are supplied to the `RelayCommand` when it is constructed because these are the parts of the command that are unique to each individual command.

Regarding the `CanExecuteChanged` event:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

When a subscriber subscribes to the event, `add` is called and when they unsubscribe, `remove` is called.  The above `CanExecuteChanged` event is just a pass-through event (i.e. if a subscriber subscribes to the `CanExecuteChanged` event, they automatically subscribe to the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event).  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested.aspx), the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event...

> occurs when the CommandManager detects conditions that might change the ability of a command to execute.

I believe that a subscriber would most likely call the `CanExecute` method on the `RelayCommand` when this event is fired to determine if the command can still be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The add/remove are like a property get/set but for events instead. The add code would be called when

```
RelayCommandInstance.CanExecuteChanged += MyChangedEventHandler
```

is executed. The remove code is called when -= is executed. You don't see this syntax very much, since you rarely need to override the default behavior of adding/removing the delegate from the events call list.

In this case, the RelayCommand is just mapping its CanExecuteChanged event to the  CommandManager.RequerySuggested event.